# VS2008 c++/cli project adds unnecessary office.dll to output folder

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dll, c++-cli, office-interop, .net-assembly

I have created a project (that behaves differently on 2 different computers, although all files are the same.

The project compiles to a managed DLL.  It is part of a solution (let's say 'solution A') that has 4 projects. This project references another project of solution A and various managed DLLs of another solution B.

On computer 1, where I did the development, it compiles as expected and it's working fine.
On computer 2, where I am mainly using the files, it compiles and it's working fine, too. But during compilation, there are 2 files added to the output folder although they are not referenced anywhere:

```
1>Kopieren von "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office12\Office.dll" in das Zielverzeichnis...
1>Kopieren von "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office12\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll" in das Zielverzeichnis...
```

I am not using those files nor referencing them or functions of them at any place in my code. Why are they copied?
It doesn't hurt though, but I would like to know if there's something going wrong.

Comment: Well, pretty safe to assume you actually need the Outlook interop files to let your program run.  Whether they get copied is determined by the Copy Local property of the reference and whether the PIA is installed on the machine.  It probably isn't.  Deploying them is never really wrong, just unnecessary if the target machine has the PIA installed.  It should, there are some failure scenarios if it is missing.

Comment: I have not modified the CopyLocal property in any project, so it is true by default. The projects are 100% identical on both computers as I copy them from one to the other. But they behave differently on compilation, that's what confuses me. // The main program and all depending assemblies are running on both computers, so if needed the office.dll must be present or I would get an assembly reference failure.

Comment: You are overlooking the role of the GAC, just have a look-see at it on both machines to compare.  High time to update your VS version btw, the "embed interop types" feature available since VS2010/.NET 4.0 is the golden solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd comment of Hans Passant to the original post is the answer.
On computer 1, both files were registered in the GAC.
On computer 2, they weren't, so they were copied to the output folder instead.
Now I gotta find out why they are needed at all...

Comment: I did not yet mark it as answer because I was not able to do so until 2 days after answering and meanwhile I simply had forgotten to do it. ;-)